# VsCode / Flutter plugin keep "Syncing files to device" after every change

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm having an annoying problem(?) when I run a flutter application. Every change I made in source code the plugin tries to sync the code with the device. This is very annoying since it slow down vscode. The unique way i found to deactive this is to stop the application, but this way I lose the benefit of hot reload.

[image]

*vscode:*

```
Version: 1.30.2
Commit: 61122f88f0bf01e2ac16bdb9e1bc4571755f5bd8
Date: 2019-01-07T22:49:48.319Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-43-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to select which app to debug in my phone debug settings and then changes were transferred to the phone instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Found an option in settings related to this behavior:

[image]